# R shiny goes into a flickering loop when csv is very big

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I built a shiny app which works very well for relatively small files (say up to 50K rows).
However when I upload a very big file and go between tabs, at some point it starts going endlessly between the tabs as if in an endless loop. It doesn't stop until I disconnect the R session.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

This happens even though I am checking a box which tells Shiny to use only a sample of the data for the drawing - but I guess the whole data still exists somewhere in the background.

Comment: This is really hard to answer without seeing the actual code. It would help if you post a reproducible example.